# Strings is stored as "??????" using FireDAC array DML

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac, firebird2.5

I have this issue when insert data to Firebird 2.5 Database using FireDAC array DML with Delphi XE7, is storing strings data as "??????" text, image below:

[image]

I have an TList and loop them passing to params:

```
//ADetalles is a TList<TServiciosDetRec>

ADataSet.Params.ArraySize := ADetalles.Count;

ADataSet.ParamByName('id').DataType := ftInteger;
ADataSet.ParamByName('nombre').DataType := ftString;
ADataSet.ParamByName('serv').DataType := ftInteger;
ADataSet.ParamByName('check').DataType := ftInteger;

for i := 0 to ADataSet.Params.ArraySize -1 do begin

  ADataSet.ParamByName('id').AsIntegers[i] := AIndex;
  ADataSet.ParamByName('nombre').AsStrings[i] := ADetalles.Items[i].SNombre; //<--- Here the Problem
  ADataSet.ParamByName('serv').AsIntegers[i] := ADetalles.Items[i].SCodigo;
  ADataSet.ParamByName('check').AsIntegers[i] := AListChecked.Items[ADetalles.IndexOf(ADetalles.Items[i])].Checked.ToInteger;

end;

ADataSet.Execute(ADataSet.Params.ArraySize,0);
```

Here the record:

```
  TServiciosDetRec = record
    SNombre: String;
    SCodigo: Integer;
    SSelected: Boolean;
  end;
```

Inserting the data one by one using normal ExecSQL, the strings stored correctly, but using execute array DML not.

Comment: For storing Unicode values use [AsWideStrings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Param.TFDParam.AsWideStrings) accessor (and data type set to [ftWideString](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.DB.TFieldType) if you want to do that explicitly). I'm saying this in case this is your problem (hard to guess from the information you've provided).

Comment: Thanks Victoria, is my English, very bad, sorry for that, when i insert data one by one using execSQL i have no problem, but very slow... i try your suggestion.

Comment: Sounds weird to me, but if you have a Unicode database and want to store Unicode values, you must use `AsWideString` accessor for storing single value and `AsWideStrings` for DML array. It's like that. If you want me or somebody else investigate about the issue you report, you must add more information. Like what encoding do you use in your database, what settings do you use for connecting from FireDAC.

Comment: Using ftWidestring and AsWideStrings[] works expectly, but, why not works with ftStrings and ASStrings[] in Array DML and normal loop ExecSQLis work, i have that doubt.. Thanks @Victoria

Comment: My Table use ISO8859_1, but is fist time with this issue after 3 years.

Comment: Still difficult to say. I'm not a Firebird expert (don't want to be), but I think you can define database, or table columns with specific character set (not tables; but maybe I'm wrong here). If you have a database defined with specific character set, have you explicitly set the `CharacterSet` in your connection parameters?

Comment: @Victoria Doesn't using wideString imply UTF16? Firebird doesn't have a UTF16 character set.

Comment: @Mark, this is documented under the [Parameter Values](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Unicode_Support_(FireDAC)#Parameter_Values) section of the Unicode topic. It must be setup to be UTF8 in the connection parameter (and the database must be of this kind). But it doesn't mean this problem arised by that (it was my guess). But you need to specify proper character set on the client side anyway, or am I wrong? Why there is a difference between single value and DML I cannot say as I don't have such old Delphi by hand. I would setup the character set and use `AsWideString(s)`.

Comment: @Victoria I know nothing about Delphi, so I can only guess at things based on my Firebird knowledge.